# Internal error when using array with type

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

```
  anforderungecc(
    sender: String
    data: [Anforderungeccdata]
    test: Boolean
    ecid: String
    receiver: String
  ): String
    @function(name: "anforderungecc-${env}")
    @auth(rules: [{ allow: private }])

type Anforderungeccdata {
  grouprequestId: String
  dateFrom: String
  dateTo: String
  ecShare: String
  energyDirection: String
  meteringPoint: String
}
```

I have this issue: Whenever i define this in my `schema.graphql` i receive an internal error when i do `amplify push`. It happens whenever i put this in brackets `data: [Anforderungeccdata]`

How do i solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

If you're making a GQL Lambda resolver, I think you just need to wrap `anforderungecc` in a QUERY or MUTATION type. For example:

```
type QUERY {
    anforderungecc(
       sender: String
       data: [Anforderungeccdata]
       test: Boolean
       ecid: String
       receiver: String
     ): String
       @function(name: "anforderungecc-${env}")
       @auth(rules: [{ allow: private }])
}

type Anforderungeccdata {
  grouprequestId: String
  dateFrom: String
  dateTo: String
  ecShare: String
  energyDirection: String
  meteringPoint: String
}
```

Use `amplify mock` to test locally before you `amplify push`.

PS: For better responses, please include the exact error you receive as part of the question. My answer solves the error I receive when I just add your schema above to mine. If your setup is somehow working and only breaks when you add the `data` field, then you need to provide more details.